# How to hide rows in table if td:nthchild(2) contains 0.00 value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table and jQuery. What I want to happen is that when a checkbox is checked, that the rows that contain the value 0.00 in a `td` are hidden. The table with the checkbox on top looks as follows:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="onlyNonZeroes">
    Hide 0.00 values
  </label>
</div> 

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="balance">0.00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="balance">1.00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="balance">0.00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To accomplish that `0.00` values are hidden I made the following code (bear with me, I am not good with this as of yet):

```
// If the onlyNonZeroes checkbox is checked we hide the rows that have 0.00 values
jQuery("#onlyNonZeroes").change(function () {
  var nonZeroCheckboxIsChecked = jQuery("#onlyNonZeroes").is(":checked");
  if (nonZeroCheckboxIsChecked) {
    $(".table tbody tr").each(function () {
      $row = $(this);
      var second = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
      if (second == 0.00) {
        $row.hide();
      }
      else {
        $row.show();
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    jQuery(".table tbody tr").each(function () {
      $row = jQuery(this);
      $row.show();
    });
  }
});
```

Hmm change of question: after having put the `jQuery(".table tbody tr")` in the function seems to work. I cannot reproduce it in JSFiddle, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j899g/1/) is my attempt.

My question boils down to this: does this code actually work or does it only look like it, and how can I improve it?

Comment: Where is the `.table` class?

Comment: Ah that's why the Fiddle did not work :-). Locally I have `<table class="table">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LYy3g/

you also need to check whether checkbox is checked or not and depending on that you hide/show rows

```
$(document).on("change", "#onlyNonZeroes", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.balance').each(function (k, element) {
            if ($(element).html() == "0.00") {
                $(element).addClass("hiderow");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.balance').removeClass("hiderow");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.hiderow {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the N possible ways, with few code change...

CSS

```
.tableBalance-NonZeroes tr {
    display: none
}
```

JS

```
var tableBalance = $(".tableBalance");
$("#onlyNonZeroes").change(function () {
    tableBalance.toggleClass("tableBalance-NonZeroes", this.checked);
    if (this.checked) {
        $(tableBalance).find("span.balance").each(function (index, element) {
            var jElement = $(element);
            jElement.parent().parent().toggle(parseFloat(jElement.text() > 0));
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('#onlyNonZeroes').click(function(e){
var elem = this;
    $('.balance').each(function(ind,val){
        if(elem.checked){
            if($(this).text()=="0.00"){
                $(this).parent().css({
                    'display':'none', 
                });
            }   
        } else{
             $(this).parent().css({
                'display':'block', 
            });
        }
    });
```

});

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb8vE/2/)

Comment: right... +1 for that... BUT why mix CSS in jquery, why not add separate class like in my solution.. its much easier..

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('#onlyNonZeroes').change(function () {
    $('td').each(function (i, e) {
        if ($(e).find('.balance').text() == '0.00') {
            $(e).parent().toggleClass('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

where the `hide` class just has a `display:none`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/j899g/6/)

Comment: Suppose the text says "10.00"...I don't think you're supposed to hide it in that case :)

Comment: @nbrooks Ah. How could I miss that? Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the value of the checkbox [changes](http://api.jquery.com/change), [loop through](http://api.jquery.com/each) the table cells which contain "0.00" and [hide/show](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) them according to the current value of the checkbox.

To get the row from the table cell, simply invoke [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) on the cell.

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/g2fLE/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#onlyNonZeroes").change(function() {
        $(".balance").each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().match(/^\s*0.00\s*$/)) {
                $(this).parent().toggle(!$("#onlyNonZeroes")[0].checked);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
$("#onlyNonZeroes").change(function () {

    var nonZeroCheckboxIsChecked = $("#onlyNonZeroes").is(":checked");
    if (nonZeroCheckboxIsChecked) {
        $("table tbody tr").each(function () {
            $row = $(this);
            if ($row.text().trim() == "0.00") {
                $row.hide();
            } else {
                $row.show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("table tbody tr").each(function () {
            $row = jQuery(this);
            $row.show();
        });
    }
});
```

Working [<kbd>Fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/j899g/4/).

**Explanation:**

First remove the `.` before table. Then directly use the text of the row it will return the same. Then trim the value before checking so that extra spaces could be removed before we can check with an already trimmed string.

Comment: what happens if there are more rows with 0.00, your solutions fails at that time..

Comment: @FabrícioMatté It looks like it was originally in the spec, then was removed? `:S` http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#content-selectors

Comment: @nbrooks Yep. I believe it was due to the lack of interest from browser vendors, or other intrinsic issues with it. Anyway Mohammad update the answer already. `=]`